# Query two nested fields on different levels with one value

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to query two nested fields on different levels so that if the value appears in one of the fields, I would get the result.

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/routines/_search?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
  "query":{
     "bool":{
        "should":[
           {
              "nested":{
                 "path":"routines",
                 "query":{
                    "nested":{
                       "path":"routines.steps",
                       "query":{
                          "nested":{
                             "path":"routines.steps.products",
                             "query":{
                                "multi_match":{
                                   "query":"Andrew Fitzsimons",
                                   "fields":[
                                      "routines.steps.products.name"
                                   ]
                                }
                             }
                          }
                       }
                    }
                 }
              }
           },
           {
              "multi_match":{
                 "query":"Andrew Fitzsimons",
                 "fields":[
                    "routines.title"
                 ]
              }
           }
        ]
     }
  }
}'
```

I am not sure I should be using boolean query or `query_string`. Would you help me in getting the idea how to implement such search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`query_string` doesn't support nested fields, so the answer is pretty clear ;-)

However, your second should clause should also be in a `nested` query since `routines` is nested:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "routines",
            "query": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "routines.steps",
                "query": {
                  "nested": {
                    "path": "routines.steps.products",
                    "query": {
                      "multi_match": {
                        "query": "Andrew Fitzsimons",
                        "fields": [
                          "routines.steps.products.name"
                        ]
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "routines",
            "query": {
              "multi_match": {
                "query": "Andrew Fitzsimons",
                "fields": [
                  "routines.title"
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```